# Generating classes based on class design - Open source tool?

Tags: c#, .net, uml

I want to design classes in a UML tool and then finally generate the classes based on the design. Are there any open source tools available for this?

Note: I'm not asking tools for creating UML diagrams. I need a tool which allows to design the classes and finally generate them as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many open tools are generating code from class diagram. You create a diagram then you get a code from it. You have Boum, Papyrus , Topcased etc..
Few tools can reverse engineer code into UML. I think Bouml and Topcased can reverse existing code.
No open source can synchronize code and model in a round trip live mechanism.
Hope this help.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio has has Visual Studio Class Designer since VS2005.

Comment: Right click in your solution, select "add/new item" and then choose "class diagram".